Simple OAuth2 client application with client_credentials grant type
I have a simple use case.
From my existing spring boot application I want to call a rest api which is protected by OAuth2 (grant type - client_credentials)
I have never worked with OAuth before.
I tried checking examples on spring-docs and other places (to my own fault chatgpt which gave incorrect suggestions).
Now I am just confused what is the correct solution.
Can someone provide me an example or nudge in the right direction towards the correct implementation.
My code so far:
application.properties
spring.application.name=oauth-test

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myuser.client-id=userId
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myuser.client-secret=userPassword
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myuser.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myuser.scope=read
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myuser.token-uri=https://auth-server-app/v1/oauth/token

Controller:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v2/")
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

    @GetMapping("/protected-data")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getProtectedData() {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient("myuser", "userId");
        String accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://my-resource-server/v1/resource/1", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Protected data retrieved successfully!");
    }
}

But when I start call the endpoint if just see:

Here is my exisitng WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private final BasicAuthConfig basicAuthConfig; // Basic @Configuration class fetching values from application properties.

  public WebSecurityConfig(final BasicAuthConfig basicAuthConfig) {
    this.basicAuthConfig = basicAuthConfig;
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    String userName = basicAuthConfig.getUsername();
    String password = basicAuthConfig.getPassword();

    String encodedPassword = encoder().encode(password);
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser(userName)
        .password(encodedPassword)
        .roles("USER");
  }


  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/v1/**").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
  }
}


What is your authorization server? Is it OIDC compliant? You named your registration myuser which makes me doubt about your ultimate intention: do you really want to call this 3rd party API as a programmatic client or do you want to send this request on behalf of a user authenticated on this 3rd party authorization server?

You need to know how the token provider accepts user credentials. There are two methods:

Username and password are accepted in the body.
Username and password are accepted in the header as "Authorization: Basic " followed by the base64 encoding of "username:password". This method is also known as Basic Auth.

In both cases, the grant type is included in the body. Ensure you confirm this detail.
Once you have this information, send a request to the /token endpoint:

For type 1, include your username and password in the body.
For type 2, format the username and password as "username:password", base64 encode it using java.util.Base64 (Java 8), and include it in the header.

The response body of the /token endpoint contains your token. You can then use this token to access resources. Typically, you cache this token and use it until it expires. It should be sent in the header of subsequent requests as "Authorization: Bearer [access token]".
Request for token Basic Auth
public String getToken() {
    
  private String token;
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
  body.put("grant_type", "your_grant_type"); 

  String auth = username + ":" + password;
  byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

  headers.set("Authorization", authHeader);
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);


  HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

  ResponseEntity<Map> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        authUrl,
        HttpMethod.POST,
        request,
        Map.class
  );

  if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK && response.getBody() != null) {
    token = (String) response.getBody().get("access_token"); // string may be diffrent
  }

  return token;
}

Access using token
public ResponseEntity<String> getSecureData( String token) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    String secureApiUrl = "endpoint"; 

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            secureApiUrl,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            entity,
            String.class
    );

    return response;
}

For understanding rest template in this code refer https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

The Spring Security OAuth2 shows a section for the scenario I think you are implementing "I want to obtain an access token for users in order to access a third-party API".
Spring security also offers some samples, and here can you find one to access Github resources by using webclient + Oauth2.0.
Based on my own experience, my advice is that you become familiar with the basics of how Oauth2 works, so that you can make sense of the flow you are implementing (client_credentials). I leave some simple resources that helped me to understand how to get started:

An Illustrated Guide to OAuth and OpenID Connect
The simplest guide to Oauth2.0
Oauth2 client credentials flow
Client credentials

